# How to solve the problem of reporting the same error in anaconda no matter what command you type

Tags: python-3.x

I tried installing pandas, but it prompted me:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution'.

I tried to uninstall PIP, but when I entered the command 
 `> python-m PIP uninstall PIP`, the same error occurred. Is there any solution?[image: error message]